# Hash key not being deleted in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, key

In Perl, in what context could you do something like this:

```
delete $ALIGN{$rna}{$dnaB};
print qq[deleted $dnaB\n] if ! exists $ALIGN{$rna}{$dnaB};
```

and then not have the print statement execute? This is giving me a huge headache. Thanks!

Comment: nope. if was using a hash ref then i'd do: delete $align_ref->{$rna}->{$dna}

Comment: I should add that the delete statement works for some keys and not others. I'm not sure why...

Comment: If `%{$ALIGN{$rna}}` was a tied hash that did something funky with `DELETE` or `EXISTS`?

Comment: %ALIGN is a global variable and I'm adding and deleting from it as I recurse with a function. maybe I shuld post the entire code??

Answer (score 4):

What you posted will delete the key.

```
$ perl -e'
   $ALIGN{$rna}{$dnaB} = "abc";
   delete $ALIGN{$rna}{$dnaB};
   print exists($ALIGN{$rna}{$dnaB}) ? qq[exists\n] : qq[doesn'\''t exist\n] ;
'
doesn't exist
```

The only case where it wouldn't is if `%{ $ALIGN{$rna} }` is a misbehaved magical variable (e.g. a misbehaved tied variable), but I strongly doubt that's the case.

What probably actually happened is that you recreated the variable in between the `delete` and the `exists`.

```
$ perl -e'
   sub foo { }
   $ALIGN{$rna}{$dnaB} = "abc";
   delete $ALIGN{$rna}{$dnaB};
   foo($ALIGN{$rna}{$dnaB}{foo});
   print exists($ALIGN{$rna}{$dnaB}) ? qq[exists\n] : qq[doesn'\''t exist\n] ;
'
exists
```